# Reading text file gives me weird string chain. cant get throu making a string variable of lines in text file

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a little script in VBS that saves command output to text file and then reading line by line from it and placing it straigh to variable.

Unfortunetly effects are weird. Instead of having a string with all lines from file I have weird chain like "ybN" (see the screenshot below). I tried to read file with many different ways found on the Internet but effects are worse or the same.

I noticed that command output is saving with many spaces after each text but I don't know if that's what causing the problem.

Any Suggestions?

```
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForReading = 1

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
    Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe" _
        , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If

Set fsoObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "D:\interfaces.txt"

WshShell.Run("%comspec% /C wmic nic where " & Chr(34) & "netconnectionid like '%'" & Chr(34) & " get netconnectionid >> " & Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34))
WScript.Echo "Interface data pushed to text file at " & strFile

If fsoObject.FileExists(strFile) Then
    If fsoObject.GetFile(strFile).Size <> 0 Then
        Set objFile = fsoObject.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForWriting)    
        objFile.Write ""
        objFile.Close  
    End If
End If

Set objFile = fsoObject.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strMsg = strMsg & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine
    'strMsg = strMsg & strLine & vbNewLine
Loop
objFile.Close

sInput = InputBox("Choose network connection to configurate " & vbNewLine & strMsg, ,"Choose one option")
```

**Screenshots:**

[image: weird chain]
[image: Saved text file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is Unicode-encoded (little endian UTF-16 to be precise). `ÿþ` is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) (BOM) for this encoding. You need to open it as such by setting the fourth parameter of [`OpenTextFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s.aspx) to `-1`:

```
Set objFile = fsoObject.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading, False, -1)
```